# How to do MAC layer padding

Tags: sockets

I am trying to send udp frames through windows sockets to a DUT but the device won't respond.
I found out that the frames which I was sending needs to be of minimum 60 bytes(MAC+IP+UDP+Payload) in length. 
I have searched a lot on enabling MAC layer padding and have not found anything.
I do not want to use winpcap here.

Comment: Do you really need it? Can't you just pad the UDP payload?

Comment: I tried that, but the DUT won't respond. Than I prepped all the headers from to UDP , added MAC padding and sent them using winpcap api's, DUT started to respond. But the problem is my team leader doesn't want to use winpcap.

Comment: Well I'm not aware of any other solution. You certainly can't control the physical layer from pure Java. Really this is a problem with the DUT. Any chance of getting it fixed?

Comment: Actually I am using C/C++ to implement this.